# trouble with swapping firstInt, middleInt, and lastInt

Tags: c#

I am trying to have the `Main()` method declare three integers named firstInt, middleInt, and lastInt. And assign those values to the variables, display them, and then pass them to a method that accepts them as reference variables, places the first value in the lastInt variable, and places the last value in the firstInt variable. In the `Main()` method, display the three variables again, demonstrating that their positions have been reversed.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    int first = 33;
    int middle = 44;
    int last = 55;

    Console.WriteLine("Before the swap the first number is {0}", first);
    Console.WriteLine("Before the swap the middle number is {0}", middle);
    Console.WriteLine("Before the swap the last number is {0}", last);

    Swap(ref first, ref middle, ref last);
    Console.WriteLine("\n============AFTER===THE===SWAP======================");
    Console.WriteLine("After the swap the first is {0}", first);
    Console.WriteLine("After the swap the middle is {0}", middle);
    Console.WriteLine("After the swap the last is {0}", last);
}

private static void Swap(ref int first, ref int middle, ref int last);

   int temp;
    temp = firstInt;
    firstInt = lastInt;
    lastInt = temp;

   }
}
```

Comment: And what's wrong with the output?

Comment: what should be the Output?

Comment: It says it cannot be found in the namespace? Is something wrong in the code?

Comment: At least give an example that can compile. If you fix the compiler warnings then this works fine, what exactly are you expecting?

Comment: @user2676862 what cannot be found..?? what namespace???

Comment: Namespace Name firstInt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
private static void Swap(ref int first, ref int middle, ref int last);

   int temp;
    temp = firstInt;
    firstInt = lastInt;
    lastInt = temp;

   }
```

You have a `;` after the parameter list of your method `Swap`, when it should be a `{` (curly brace):

```
private static void Swap(ref int first, ref int middle, ref int last)
{

    int temp;
    temp = firstInt;
    firstInt = lastInt;
    lastInt = temp;
}
```

Your code generates a "Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected." error.

**EDIT**

As others have pointed out, you also have the wrong variables name - it should be `first`, `middle` and `last`, so you're whole method would be:

```
private static void Swap(ref int first, ref int middle, ref int last)
{

    int temp;
    temp = first;
    first = last;
    last = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You were mixed up between `first` and `firstInt`, `last` and `lastInt`:

```
private static void Swap(ref int first, ref int middle, ref int last){
 int temp = first;
 first = last;
 last = temp;
}
```

Comment: opps didn't see that thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why I am answering but this is all simple compile problems

```
   private static void Swap(ref int first, ref int middle, ref int last); <-- semicolon should not be here
      <-- missing bracket
       int temp;
        temp = firstInt; <-- none of these names exist
        firstInt = lastInt;
        lastInt = temp;

    }
```

Should be:

```
    private void Swap(ref int first, ref int middle, ref int last)
    {
        int temp;
        temp = first;
        first = last;
        last = temp;
    }
```

Comment: Oh my mistake for messing up the name of first and last with firstInt and LastInt.

Answer (score 0):

Or with some XOR swapping goodness (no temp variable):

```
private static void Swap(ref int first, ref int middle, ref int last) {
    first ^= last;
    last ^= first;
    first ^= last;
}
```

Comment: I declared temp by the "int temp" = first;

Comment: Yes but my version does the same thing without the temp variable.