# How would I go about making a method that reverses the position of 4 variables?

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a program which contains a method that reverses the positions of four variables. Write a Main() method that demonstrates the method works correctly. How would I go about doing this I'm new to C#.

Comment: Reverses the positions of four variables....could the requirement be any more vague?  If this is a school assignment and that's all the instructor gave you, I'd ask them for more information.

Comment: If it were not for the capital `T`, i would have thought your were talking to yourself. ;)

Comment: I think the OP may want to rename and change `t` to `T` :)))

Comment: Wow.. this is awfully similar to this question posted minutes ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18584401/trouble-with-swapping-firstint-middleint-and-lastint. I hope you get a better tutor one day you two!

Comment: @KingKing - But my avatar is better :)

Comment: Can someone know what to do this is all the instructor said to do. Is'nt there hundreds of diffrent ways to do the same thing?

Comment: What t? the question starts with how???

Comment: @tim - Then you really need to ask your instructor to be more clear in what he wants you to do.  Yes, there are a lot of ways to do this, and only *some* of those ways will be what the instructor is expecting.  "positions" is a very ambiguous word.

Comment: @tim - Valamas comment was directed to me and my comment (the first comment). My profile name starts with a capital T.

Comment: If I were to make a guess, assuming you're at the beginning of the course, your instructor is probably talking about an array of 4 elements and reversing that.  But that's only a guess.

Comment: He just said to have a method that reverses the positions of four variables

Comment: and then just have that method display the varibles in reverse order.

Comment: @tim - That's all he said?  He didn't say what these variables were or how they were stored?  What are you studying right now?  Arrays?  Lists?  Structs?  Something else?

Comment: Have you learned anything about arrays or loops yet?

Comment: alittle we have done the while loop and a for loop?

Comment: But seriously, `Console.WriteLine(new int[4]{1,2,3,4}.Reverse());` try it.

Comment: @user1306322 - While that would work, I highly doubt that OP's **instructor** is looking for that.

Comment: Like this  Console.WriteLine("Numbers in normal order: {0},{1},{2},{3}", first, second, third, fourth);
            Reverse(ref first, ref second, ref third, ref fourth);
            Console.WriteLine("Numbers in inverse order: {0},{1},{2},{3}", first, second, third, fourth);

Comment: @user1306322 that's OK but I think the OP's **exercise** is to use some **sorting algorithm** to reverse it, we have many kinds of `sorting algorithm`, the most simple one is `selection sort`.

Comment: This is just progamming 1 class I dont think we know these simplfied shorcuts yet :)

Comment: Ah....this **does** look familiar, per @SimonWhitehead earlier comment.  You'll need to use a temp variable or two in your method to swap the numbers around.

Comment: @user1306322 - If I was an instructor and one of my students did that, and he could not explain *how* (or at least one way) internal code of that method would accomplish the reversal, I would flunk him on the assignment.  The instructor's purpose is to teach the students the *how* of programming, not the shortcuts.  You have to be able to walk before you can run.

Comment: Can somebody please include [the full text of the assignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18584644/how-would-i-go-about-making-a-method-that-reverses-the-position-of-4-variables#comment27348787_18585011) into the question? My [suggested edit got rejected](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2846099) as "attempt to reply to the existing post" >:( reviewers these days!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think OP is looking for this

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int first = 111;
        int second = 222;
        int third = 333;
        int fourth = 444;
        Console.WriteLine("Numbers in normal order: {0},{1},{2},{3}", first, second, third, fourth);
        Reverse(ref first, ref second, ref third, ref fourth);
        Console.WriteLine("Numbers in inverse order: {0},{1},{2},{3}", first, second, third, fourth);

        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter To Exit");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void Reverse(ref int first1, ref int second2, ref int third3, ref int fourth4)
    {

        int temp, temp1;
        temp = first1;
        first1 = fourth4;
        temp1 = second2;
        second2 = third3;
        third3 = temp1;
        fourth4 = temp;
}
```

Comment: What was the original assignment, again? Are you two guys by any chance in one class?

Comment: It rather defeats the purpose of learning to hand someone the complete code to an assignment.

Comment: How about `Console.WriteLine("Numbers in normal order: {0},{1},{2},{3}", first, second, third, fourth);
            Console.WriteLine("Numbers in inverse order: {3},{2},{1},{0}", first, second, third, fourth);` :)

Comment: arent you user user1306322 I am confused

Comment: oh user2676862 your talking about?

Comment: @tim you should focus on your assignment. Can you remember or find the exact wording and include it in your question? (and here I thought two Tims was confusing)

Comment: Create a new program named Reverse4, which contains a method that reverses the positions of four variables. Write a Main() method that demonstrates the method works correctly.

Comment: `reverses the positions of four variables` ????

Comment: positions same thing as order in which they are displayed